# SSIS error loading postgres "timeout expired " Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, postgis, oledbconnection

I am loading data into a potgres database using ssis and oledb drivers. The package executes inserts and some updates using execute sql task. It runs fine through most of the steps but then fails on one final update sql task and I receive the following cryptic Microsoft error msg.

failed with the following error: "timeout expired
". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.”

The target postgres servers are sitting on ubuntu and it seems that the ssis package runs successfully on one server then randomly fails on another.

Comment: Do you have more than one command firing off at the same time using the same connection?  Aka parallel inserts?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your control flow and data flow?

Comment: @JustBob the error message happens only on one execute sql task to update postgis geometries. The geometry update uses two spatial functions st_geomfromtext and st_transform. It is a separate step from the inserts/updates and uses the same connection. I'll try to post the control flow/dataflow.

Comment: I asked because when trying to share a connection (open the connection once and make many calls on that single connection) among ~15 sql tasks in parallel I would get a generic/confusing time out message similar to yours.  Once I lowered the amount of concurrent sql tasks down to ~3 the issue went away.  So if you can I would play with making sure only one task is using the connection at a time and see if that helps at all and upping it to see if you can consistently reproduce it. I was using oledb for SQL Server so I might be off target here.

Comment: looks like I need a reputation of at least 10 to upload images